# Query to join tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 3 tables:
product, category and product_to_category.

**product**

```
id     name
1      monitor
2      computer
3      speaker
4      lcd
5      microphone
```

**category**

```
id     name
1      displays
2      speakers
```

**product_to_category**

```
id     product_id      category_id
1      1               1
2      4               1
3      3               2
```

I need something like this: all products in category "speakers" and those which are not in any category (computer and microphone)

```
product_id   product_name
2            computer
3            speaker
5            microphone
```

I need all in one query. I have done with two queries, but i need all in one query because 
[http://datatables.net/](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/server_side.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternate `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT product.id, product.name
FROM product
LEFT JOIN product_to_category AS ptc
  ON product.id = ptc.product_id
WHERE IFNULL(ptc.category_id, 0) IN(0, 2);
```

SQL Fiddle Link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7aaeff/8

Comment: WORKING!!! I just added "GROUP BY product.id"

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Select 
  Product.id,product.name
From
  product 
    left outer join product_to_category As ptc 
    on product.id = ptc.product_id
Where 
  ptc.category_id = 2 
  or 
  isnull(ptc.id,0)=0
Group by 
  product.id, product.name
```

Use `ifnull` instead of `isnull` if using mysql..

Comment: I'am using mysql.Not ok.
Now its return row only if product is in category.
If is product in more than in one category, return all categorys as one row.
I would like to be each product visible only once.
And if there is more than one category, ignore all other.

Comment: I apologize for the poor explanation. I am new to forums in general

Comment: This solution does work.  Here is a link to SQL Fiddle using your example information, and this solution's results (which match your expected results): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7aaeff/6

Comment: For this example works. I should enter a more extensive table. In my real table does not work

Comment: @user2997954 Updated answer for unique results..